# SonarQube Project Does Not Get Analyzed by JavaScript Profile

Tags: javascript, java, css, sonarqube

We have two Java web application projects being analyzed by the same instance of SonarQube (version 6.4). Both of these projects have Java, JavaScript, and CSS components and we would like to run analysis for those profiles.

Project A is successfully being analyzed for all three languages while Project B is only being analyzed for Java.

The global settings are pretty much out-of-the-box and neither project has any project-specific settings.

We don't think it should have any impact, but Project A is a Spring MVC application that uses JSPs. Project B is a Spring Boot application that uses Thymeleaf.

Project A does not have a sonar.properties or sonar-project.properties file. On Project B we have tried it without any properties and with properties trying to name it both sonar.properties and sonar-project.properties that set the sonar.language either js alone or java,js,css, but there appears to be no difference in behavior.

SonarQube is getting kicked off by Jenkins (version 2.61) with the SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins (version 2.6.1) plugin.

Both Jenkins projects are similarly configured and start the Sonar analysis as a Post Build Step:

```
$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SQ_LOGIN -Dsonar.password=$SQ_PASSWORD
```

We have even tried dropping the Sonar database and having Sonar rebuild it, but Project B is still only being analyzed for Java.

**EDIT:** We would like project B to be analyzed by Java, JavaScript, and CSS just like Project A is.

Comment: Yes, we want Project B to be analyzed by Java, JavaScript, and CSS just like Project A.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a Maven analysis is not going to include resources files into the analysis. You need to do that manually by overriding `sonar.sources` either as a property in your pom or by defining (`-D`) it on the command line. I would guess that has been done in a property in the pom of the project that's being scanned like you want.

Comment: $SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SQ_LOGIN -Dsonar.password=$SQ_PASSWORD -Dsonar.sources=src/main fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to G. Ann's answer I was able to solve a similar problem. In a multi-module Maven project, in the midst of several Java modules, there was one, appropriately called `frontend`, that contained exclusively Web resources such as HTML, CSS and JavaScript files. These sources were in `app`, and not in `src/main/web`. For SonarQube to analyze these web resources I added `<sonar.sources>app</sonar.sources>` in the `<properties />` element of the pom of the frontend module. Quite surprisingly, for the build to work for all modules, I had to add `<sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>` in the pom of the next module in the build order, to override the now redefined default value.